# Paired t test: standard deviation of mean versus mean difference

Tags: t-test, paired-data

I would be grateful if you could help me answering to a review I received:

I have a sample that was evaluated in two different moments for the same outcome (n=80, normal distribution, Mean 1=272±20, Mean 2=283±30)

I performed a two tailed paired t test for comparing the means. The result was: mean diff=11±27; t=-3.5, df 79, p=0.001

...and I received a comment mentioning that the these values could not be true because the standard deviation of the original means was 2-3 times wider than the mean difference.. I know that the test was done properly but I don't know how to argue ... Could you please help me answering to this?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your numbers are completely inconsistent.  Could you therefore show the details of your calculations of the $\pm 27$ (and explain what that number represents), $-3.5,$ and $0.001$?

Comment: Of course, I'm sorry about that. So: I have the same sample evaluated in moment 1 and moment 2 for the same outcome. The mean in the moment 1 was 272, standard deviation 20. The mean in the moment 2 was 283, standard deviation 30. The mean difference between two evaluations was 11, standard deviation 27. I've performed a paired t test and obtained a t value of -3.5, with 79 degrees of freedom, p=0.001

Comment: With those numbers, (1) $27$ is a standard deviation, whereas you ought to be reporting a standard error of $27/\sqrt{80}=3.0$ in this context; (2) $t = -3.64$ (and notice the negative sign); (3) $p=0.00048.$